# AJAX Request is sent in UTF-8, but Servlet does not recognize special chars

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, utf-8

The problem occurs when creating an AJAX request containing umlauts like ä,ü,ö. I create an AJAX request from the Website  like this:

JS:

```
var r = new window.XMLHttpRequest(),
    p;


r.open('POST', AppConfig.SERVICES_URL, true);
r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8;");
r.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
r.withCredentials = true;
params = 's=' + s + '&m=' + m + '&t=' + t + '&q' + JSON.stringify(query);

console.log('----------->PARAMS: ' + p);
```

And finally I send the request with:

```
r.send(p);
```

If I check the console output of the browser everything is fine:

[image]

If I check the request on the serverside:

(Java Servlet, dopPost-Method)

```
    // GET POST REQUEST DATA
    System.out.println("charEncoding: "+ request.getCharacterEncoding());
    //request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String query = request.getParameter("q");
    System.out.println("query : " + query);
```

I get following output on the console:

[image]

Also the char encoding of the request is utf-8. What could be the reason of this?

Comment: Display the character as `(int)query.charAt(18)` (check the count) and if it displays 252, the data has been transmitted correctly.

Comment: What Servlet container are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`getCharacterEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getCharacterEncoding%28%29) method only

> Returns the name of the character encoding used **in the body of this request.**

But you are sending your parameters as part of the URI query string, not the request body. You can't depend on `setCharacterEncoding(String)` for that purpose.

In Tomcat (and I assume other containers have similar configuration), there's a configuration attribute you can set to have the container use the same encoding for both the request body and the query string. That is [`useBodyEncodingForURI`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html). You can set it on a (HTTP) `<Connector>` element of your Tomcat instance's `server.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific: I use the IBM Websphere Application Server 7,

As Sotirios Delimanolis mentioned, there was a problem with the URI encoding of the servlet container. The query was sent UTF-8 encoded but the URI intepreted it with another encoding. The solution was to add a custom property for the webcontainer (com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.decodeParamViaReqEncoding) as mentioned in [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM84811).

This solution is available after the fixpack WAS 7.0.0.31 or higher!